# Restful resource naming for new element with relations

Tags: web-services, rest

I'm trying to understand REST naming with this example.

Suppose I want to create a new company with this relations:

Company <--->> CompanyTaxes <<----> Taxes

Taxes is a global Entity, and CompanyTaxes are the selected Taxes for this company.

In the creation of a new Company I have to list all the existing Taxes in order to check or uncheck one or many taxes to use. Then, following REST resource naming I think the better option is to use:

GET /Companies/{0}/Taxes: if the id of the company is 0 then I list all taxes.
GET /Companies/123456/Taxes: if the id is 123456 then I send the list of all taxes and mark those that the company has selected.

Is that ok, or I have to move the Taxes so they can be independent of the Company?

In the case of a new Company:

GET /Taxes/: get all the taxes and render them on the UI

In the case of an existing company:

GET /Taxes/: get all the taxes
GET /Company/123456/Taxes: get the taxes from Company 123456

Then, in the UI I have to match the taxes from company with the global ones in order to check/uncheck selected.

What is the better option? In the first case the server sends the information of all the taxes, along with the selected. In the second case the UI is responsible for the match in order to show which taxes are selected.

Greetings!

Comment: Neither is better than the other. What it will really depend on is how YOU want to group your services together. It will have to be answered by you because you know, or have an idea of, how your application will grow and how to group your APIs. If you want a separate taxes only API use just Taxes (assuming that there are more features to the Taxes API like /Taxes/123456/Year/2013. If company info is grouped together, then prefix with Company. Just document your choices for future users.